# Sensenet Move Server

Tags: sensenet

I'm simply trying to move a site created by a third party to a new server. I'm getting an assembly error but I checked the project is set to move references local. I'm not familiar with sensenet so thought maybe someone could help.

```
ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +9
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +61
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.TypeHandler.GetTypesByBaseType(Type baseType) in \Source\SenseNet\Storage\TypeHandler.cs:211

[ApplicationException: Type discovery error. Assembly: BotDetect.Web.Mvc, Version=4.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=74616036388b765f]
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.TypeHandler.GetTypesByBaseType(Type baseType) in \Source\SenseNet\Storage\TypeHandler.cs:230
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.NodeTypeManager.GatherNodeObservers() in \Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\NodeTypeManager.cs:123
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.NodeTypeManager.StartEventSystem() in \Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\NodeTypeManager.cs:130
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.NodeTypeManager.get_Current() in Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\NodeTypeManager.cs:50
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.StartManagers() in Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:230
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.DoStart() in Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:125
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in \Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:98
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Repository.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in \Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Repository.cs:58
   SenseNet.Portal.SenseNetGlobal.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application) in \Source\SenseNet\Portal\SenseNetGlobal.cs:67
   SenseNet.Portal.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Xavor\NVIP(Latest)\Source\SenseNet\Portal\Global.cs:9

[HttpException (0x80004005): Type discovery error. Assembly: BotDetect.Web.Mvc, Version=4.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=74616036388b765f]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +10096597
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +218
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Type discovery error. Assembly: BotDetect.Web.Mvc, Version=4.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=74616036388b765f]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10077812
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, the library in the error message (BotDetect.Web.Mvc) is not part of sensenet, it is likely to be related to a custom node observer (because the error occurs during loading node observers). A custom node observer is a class that implements the sensenet node observer API and it must be in one of the custom libraries. I suggest checking the dependencies this BotDetect requires.

Comment: Thank you I will check this. I did notice that and tried to import a new class for BotDetect but I thought it was just a handler and with the type error it's referencing the source location, including drive path, from a local dll. I'll double check it all.